# Problema para compartir una clase estática entre una librería y un servicio (?)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, servicio

Buenas, tengo una solución con varios proyectos. Uno de ellos es de negocio (llamemos a este proyecto prN), donde se realizan una serie de procesos y los resultados se van guardando en una clase estática.

Otro de los proyectos es para un servicio, al cual se le llamará para pedirle la información que se ha guardado en esa clase estática (llamamos a este proyecto prS).

Mi problema es que cuando llamo al servicio no consigo acceder a la información de la clase estática, es decir, en el código accedo a ella pero no tiene la información real, la clase aparece vacía pese a que esté modificada por el proyecto prN.

Me da la sensación de que los proyectos no corren bajo la misma solución. Cuando arranco la solución desde el proyecto prN, el servicio de prS se activa pero no ve la información de la clase estática en cuestión. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto para que el servicio vea la clase estática en tiempo real, con la información que verdaderamente tiene?

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: No es que no corran en la misma solucion. Basicamente, cada vez que se llama al webservice se crea una nueva instancia de este, con acceso a una clase estatica vacia. Debes modificar el diseño de tu aplicación, usar clases estaticas nunca suele ser una buena idea.

Comment: @Pikoh , pero necesito pasar esa información. Lo único que se me ocurre es guardarla en ficheros... pero tiene que haber algún modo de compaginar ambos proyectos... y pasar información entre ellos si tener que usar ficheros o BBDD, no ?

Comment: Es muy dificil ayudarte sin saber exactamente que hace tu capa de negocio, pero lo normal sería que tu webservice llamara directamente a un método de tu proyecto de negocio, o bien usar efectivamente algun archivo/base de datos para almacenar la información generada por tu proyecto de negocio

Comment: @Pikoh , hombre la capa de negocio tiene miga, pero en definitiva saca tres parámetros (3 strings) en una clase estática (necesito que sea estática porque a la vez se accede desde otros proyectos de la solución). Pues lo que necesito es que al llamar al servicio me envíe esos tres parámetros, ¿Con esta información se te ocurre algo? PD: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda y tiempo!

Comment: Lamentablemente has dado con alguien que no es nada partidario de clases estaticas para almacenar información. Si el proceso que se realiza no es muy costoso, yo crearía un metodo que generase esos tres parámetros en el momento y lo llamaría desde el webservice. Si es costoso...yo usaría una base de datos, o un archivo json por ejemplo. Hay tambien que tener cuidado con la concurrencia, que podria dar problemas...De todas maneras, quizá alguien te pueda dar otra idea mejor

Comment: He pensado también en enviar desde la capa de negocio la información al servicio, de modo que se almacene en el proyecto de servicio y de este modo hago la información accesible al cliente cuando la pida...

Comment: Hola, con la descripción presupongo que lo que quiere @M.Blonde es realizar una comunicación interprocesos. Aunque compartan el mismo proyecto de clases estáticas, en realidad cada proceso usa su propio `AppDomain` separando las aplicaciones y sus correspondientes datos. Le propongo que implemente un sistema usando sockets o pipes. Más info de anonymous pipes en [Cómo: Usar canalizaciones anónimas para la comunicación local entre procesos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb546102(v=vs.110).aspx)